# Reputation changes are constantly out of sync between the new meta bar and my SO account

Tags: discussion, reputation, top-bar

Reputation changes are constantly out of sync with SO account:

This is how it first look on my SO account:
[image: my SO account reputation tab]

This is the reputation changes I see in the new bar (which I opened later) :
[image: reputation changes in the new bar]

**shouldn't the reputation changes in the new bar show only "new" notifications?** (that wasn't read somewhere else, in this case - it shouldn't show anything..).

This happened to me multiple times today (even if I opened meta an hour after I already saw the change in SO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should clear on all browsers when you open the achievements dropdown on *any* site in *any* browser (via websockets).  I'll be tracking down why this isn't working today.

If you have websockets blocked, that's another issue, and you won't see it until the next pageload - but I believe the clear case isn't working across browsers currently...I'll get to that this morning since it'll get annoying fast.

*Note*: It should **not** clear when viewing your per-site reputation profile, that's not a network-wide number and is a different number.

Comment: I am using chrome, and have no websockets blocked.

Comment: @Yosi a fix for reputation clear that syncs *all sites with the new top bar* is rolling out now.  It'll be more effective once all sites have the top bar of course, but that shouldn't be too far in the future.

Comment: good, and it's not a critical bug, then it's more then ok..