# Reputation changes differ between web and iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, ios-app, top-bar

There is a discrepancy between my network-wide reputation changes when viewed on the web (+498):

[image]

...and when viewed on the iOS app (+490):

[image]

I do know that I had 10+ reputation on [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), 20+ reputation on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com) and the remainder (+468) on [TeX - LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

I understand that a difference of -2 could result from [a downvote not showing up in the top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208900/168244). To that end, I achieved +470 on TeX - LaTeX. That doesn't explain the difference.

<sub>Unrelated: [Reputation shown is less than what it really is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266348/168244)</sub>

Comment: I don't think this is related: [Reputation changes are constantly out of sync between the new meta bar and my SO account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207540/168244)

Comment: When calculating the reputation to display, the app only considers the last 100 achievements (votes + badges + things like wiki approvals, users deleted).  If all of them were question up votes, you'd max at 500.  If some are down votes, badges, etc, and some are answer up votes, I could see the amount being higher or lower than 500.  It may be reasonable to check the next page *if* the 100th item is unread but I would much rather you just tap the number and clear it. :)

Comment: It turns out you're *very* popular.  The app was only looking at the **50** most recent achievements so you were pretty much maxing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be pretty much fixed in 1.4.3.3.

The app updates that number two ways:

1. If you're in the app and a reputation generating event occurs, you get a realtime notification of the change.  These should perfectly match the web because they come from the same source.
2. Every time the app has a cold start or (returns from background and it has been at least **M** minutes since the last attempt), it downloads the **N** most recent achievements and sums up the score.

Before M was 60 and N was 50, so A) if you left the app and came back with it still in memory, the value wouldn't update, and B) if you had more than 50 unread achievements we would miss some of them in the calculation.

I'm going ahead and dropping M to 5 minutes because 60 is really unreasonable especially with the 6s keeping apps in memory so long.  I'm also increasing N to 100 because that's already the number of items we load for the achievement dialog.

This is an imperfect solution because you could easily keep not tapping that for days but I'm calling it close enough.  Otherwise I could just look to see if all 100 achievements are unread and replace the number with "".