# Is "today" for reputation considered a different interval in the Android app versus web-app?

Tags: support, bug, android-app, achievements-dialog, web

These two screenshots were taken at the same time.

[image]

[image]

The values for many of the questions are higher for the web-app. Maybe it is because the Android app considers some of the rep I gained to have happened "yesterday"? (That is just a loose hypothesis.)

I've noticed that sometimes the rep gains displayed by the app keep going down (5 or 10 at a time) as time goes on. I suppose maybe that's because upvotes get further away in time and are thus no longer "today"? I don't think that's the case for the web-app.

Do the web-app and the Android-app calculate "today" differently? IMO they should both do it in the same way, in order not to confuse users.

I have SE 1.0.85 for Android. My time zone is Indian Standard Time.

By the way, this is *not* a duplicate of [this.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268116/321647) That one is about the iOS app, and I'm not sure if it's the same issue either. The accepted answer there says it's gonna be solved in some other version of the iOS app.